# how can I write this assembly line differently?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is there a way that we can rewrite the below assembly operation using only **mov** instruction

```
movzx   eax, WORD  [short_temp]
```

Comment: Although inefficient you can use 2 _mov_ instructions. `mov eax, 0` `mov ax, [short_temp]`. There are better ways if your question doesn't have to be interpreted literally (ie. using _only_ mov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, easily. Just zero out `eax` and set `ax` afterwards:

```
XOR EAX, EAX
MOV AX, [short_temp]
```

If you want to obtain a word from `[EAX]` as you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412302/how-can-i-write-this-assembly-line-differently/41412307#comment70028372_41412307), just store the address to some other register beforehand:

```
MOV EBX, EAX
XOR EAX, EAX
MOV AX, [short_temp]
```

or, if that's not possible, do as [@fuz proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412302/how-can-i-write-this-assembly-line-differently/41412307#comment70028529_41412307) and clear the upper 16 bits of `EAX` using `AND`:

```
MOV AX, [EAX]
AND EAX, FFFFh
```

Comment: I have not downvoted you, but this does not meet OP's requirement as it also uses the `XOR` instruction.

Comment: what if `movzx eax, WORD  [eax]`

Comment: @fuz I cannot imagine that the OP meant use of just **one** instruction, i.e., `mov`. Why have `movzx` if it can be expressed using `mov`?

Comment: No idea either, but these are OP's requirements.

Comment: @arnoldasllani Consider using `mov ax, [short_temp]` and then `and ax, FFFFj`.

Comment: @arnoldasllani Then you use `eax` for indirect addressing. Simple textual replacement that should be.

Comment: @fuz `and eax, FFFFh`, isn't it? That's bigger than my solution I think because of the 4-byte immediate.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if `eax` is the index register.

Comment: xor-zeroing avoids a partial-register penalty on Intel CPUs for reading EAX after writing AX.  It should definitely be preferred if you for some reason want to avoid MOVZX.  I have no idea why you'd want to use only MOV instructions, but `mov eax,0` would work, too.

Comment: @fuz Fixed now.

Comment: Even though `XOR` is functionally free (either because it's implemented via register renaming on modern processors, or because you can interleave it within other instructions to hide its cost on older processors), this code will actually be slower than `MOVZX` because of the 16-bit prefix required for that second `MOV` instruction. The `AND` version is even worse—there are penalties all over the place lurking there!

Answer (score 4):

You never need to avoid `movzx`.  If 32-bit registers like EAX are available, then your code is running on a 386 or later so `movzx` is supported, too.

It's by far the most efficient way to do this on an Intel CPU.  `movzx r32, [memory]` decodes to just a load uop, with no ALU operation.  The latency is the same as normal load (IIRC), so the zero extension is done for free by the load unit.

On an AMD Bulldozer-family CPU, `movzx` always uses an ALU port (as well as a load port when it's a memory operand), so it could in theory be faster to xor-zero EAX before using a word-load (@Downvoter's answer).  This might give you one cycle lower load-use latency at the cost of larger code-size and more m-ops for the frontend to decode.

Other suggestions like doing a word-load into AX and then `and eax, 0xFFFF` are obviously worse, because of reading EAX after a partial-register write (of AX), and because it's a separate ALU operation that adds another cycle of latency.  ([xor-zeroing avoids the partial-register penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/224132), even on Intel P6-family CPUs.)